# Match objects matrix in world space - Three.js

Tags: 3d, three.js

I am trying to learn the correct way to manipulate objects in world space. As a test I have created a cube and I am drawing some lines from an arbitrary vector to each vertex on the cube.

If I don't change the cube in any way then the lines hit the vertices nicely:

[image: correct]

but if I rotate the cube, then the lines no longer match the vertices:

[image: wrong]

Obviously I know I could rotate the line by the same amount as I am rotating the cube, but I know I should be manipulating matrices or vectors to do this.

Can anyone explain how I should be approaching common issues like this, without needing to rotate both objects.

For convenience I have a [jsfiddle to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/SCXNQ/110/)

Comment: Do you want the origin of the lines stay at the same world position while the ends of the lines match the vertices of the cube? Or do you want to rotate both objects at the same time so it follows the original structure?

Comment: Any chance you could explain both? Its a learning exercise, I've started reading about vectors and matrices but I'm unsure where to apply them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the lines to rotate with the code you just need to add the line to the cube instead of to the scene:

```js
// scene.add(line);
cube.add(line);
```

However, if what you want is to keep the origin of the lines at the same position and update the end of the lines instead.

```js
cube.updateMatrixWorld(); // make sure that cube.matrixWorld is updated.

for(var i = 0; i < 8 ;i++){
   var vertex = cube.matrixWorld.multiplyVector3(cube.geometry.vertices[i].clone());
   lineGeometry.vertices.push(vertex);
   lineGeometry.vertices.push(lineStart); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its the second part of your answer that I need to learn more about, the whole thing with mixing coordinate space, I'll get there.

Comment: Every object has the properties `matrix` and `matrixWorld`. `matrix` stores the local position, rotation and scale. `matrixWorld` stores the position, rotation and scale of the object in the world (taking in consideration its parent and the parents of the parent, ... ). If you want to "transform" a point into the local space of an object, you need to multiply the point using the matrixWorld. Not sure if this clarifies anything, this is always hard to explain...